# I'm a novice not sure where to get a bike education?

Tags: single-speed

Like most kids I road everywhere through high school than my biking waned to the neighborhood rides with my kids when they came along.  Currently I have a Schwinn Single Speed Cruiser that my dad special ordered for my mom from a Schwinn shop in the late 80's/early 90's. She didn't ride it much and I've had it about 18 years and my hubby has kept it maintained for me. I have no knowledge of bike vocab/lingo but want to extend my biking skills and ride more trails.  I don't know where to start, don't know if I have the best bike although at this point it's what I can afford.  Advice?

Comment: Are you interested in learning about maintaining your bike, improving your riding skills, or both?

Answer (score 3):

I would inquire at your local bike shop or look on the internet for a local bike advocacy group in your area.  These are generally a fantastic resource. 
Some of the education my local group offers are below, additionally they also have regular rides, both adult and family oriented. I have heard of other groups offering comparable resources all over the US and Canada. If you happen to be in the US, [The League of American Bicyclists](http://www.bikeleague.org) has a search tool to find local groups.

- Youth Education
- Confident City Cycling
- Basic Maintenance Skills
- Safe Routes to Schools
- Resources for Employers

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin Kelley, I am in the US and will google these resources now.

Comment: The League also offers classes in many locations.

Answer (score 2):

To learn the vocab/lingo, I suggest Tom Cuthbertson's "Anybody's Bike Book," which is out of print but can usually be found for a few dollars on Amazon.com.  There are some terrific drawings in the book that name the various parts and show where they are.  It's also an entertaining read, although I also like "Chainbreaker" by Ethan Clark and Shelley Lynn Jackson.

For actually doing repairs, Youtube is essential.  just search for videos on any subject regarding bikes and you'll get plenty of choices.  I myself gravitated to videos by the Park Tool company, Global Cycling Network and RJ The Bike Guy.

Incidentally, that old Schwinn could be worth significant money, depending on its condition (rust, etc.).  Lots of folks enjoy refurbishing a good old Schwinn from the 80s.

Have fun!

Comment: Be wary of utube videos. Many are very good, but I have seen a few too many where the person is an idiot, and is doing something badly wrong - especially work arounds for not having the correct tool for the job.  They get away with it without any obvious damage, but that does not mean you will.

Comment: @JoeHeller thank you for the book suggestions, I'll definitely look into them and check out the sources you listed for Youtube.  I'll be keeping my bike though, not only do I still ride it (it's in great shape) but there's the sentimental reasons of where it came from as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look for cycling clubs and local bike shops (usually abbreviated to 'LBS' here) in your area.

Many cycling clubs cater to casual riders and organize group rides that include casual groups. Many local bike shops also organize group rides that cater to casual riders.

Riding with like-minded others so a great way to learn about cycling and find trails in your area suitable for the type of riding you want to do.